# MongoDB + Google Big Query - Normalize Data and Import to BQ

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery

I've done quite a bit of searching, but haven't been able to find anything within this community that fits my problem.

I have a MongoDB collection that I would like to normalize and upload to Google Big Query. Unfortunately, I don't even know where to start with this project.

What would be the best approach to normalize the data? From there, what is recommended when it comes to loading that data to BQ?

I realize I'm not giving much detail here... but any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python, easy way is to read collection chunky and use pandas' `to_gbq` method. Easy and quite fast to implement. But better to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer provided by SirJ, you have multiple options to load data to BigQuery, including loading the data to Cloud Storage, local machine, Dataflow any more as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#overview).  [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage) supports data in [multiple formats](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#supported_data_formats) such as CSV, JSON, Avro, Parquet and more. You also have [various options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_new_table) to load data using Web UI, Command Line, API or using the Client Libraries which support C#, GO, Java, Node.JS, PHP, Python and Ruby.